# Installed NumPy successfully, but not accessible with virtualenv

Tags: python, ubuntu, numpy, virtualenv

I have successfully install NumPy on Ubuntu; however when inside a virtualenv, NumPy is not available. I must be missing something obvious, but I do not understand why I can not import NumPy when using python from a virtualenv. Can anyone help? I am using Python 2.7.3 as my system-wide python and inside my virtualenv. Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You have to install it inside of your virtual environment. The easiest way to do this is:

1. source [virtualenv]/bin/activate
2. pip install numpy

Comment: Both pip and easy_install failed within virtualenv. I installed NumPy with apt-get on Ubuntu.

Comment: Are you using Python 2.x or 3.x?
You could also try this inside of your virtualenv:
http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/installing.html